# calculate less number of hops C#

Tags: c#

Good morning :) I'm working on C# and I want to write a code that can calculate the less number of hops from any point to particular point, as a picture show

[click here to show the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6qRT.jpg)

I have points from 1 to 12, so if I want to calculate the less number of hops from the point 12 to 1 it will be 1 with counterclockwise not 11 hops with clockwise.
another example to clarify my question, if I want to calculate the less number of hops from the point 11 to 4 it will be 5 with counterclockwise not 6 hops with clockwise. notice : the number of points may be an odd number.
I hope you understand my question ..

Comment: Do you need to know if the answer is clockwise or anticlockwise, or will just the minimum number of steps suffice?

Comment: If you DO need to know if the answer is clockwise or anticlockwise, in the case where the number of steps is 6 do you prefer the answer to be clockwise 6 or anticlockwise 6?

Answer (score 4):

Try *clockwise*, *anticlockwise* and take *minimum*:

```
private static int Hops(int a, int b) {
  return Math.Min((12 + a - b) % 12, (12 + b - a) % 12);
}
```

Tests:

```
// 5
Console.WriteLine(Hops(11, 4));
// 1
Console.WriteLine(Hops(12, 1));
```

**Edit**: As Matthew Watson has mentioned in comments, you may want to know whether it *clockwise* or *anticlockwise*:

```
private static int ClockwiseHops(int a, int b) {
  return (12 + b - a) % 12;
}

private static int AntiClockwiseHops(int a, int b) {
  return (12 + a - b) % 12;
}

private static int Hops(int a, int b) {
  return Math.Min(ClockwiseHops(a, b), AntiClockwiseHops(a, b));
}

private static String Solve(int a, int b) {
  int hops = Hops(a, b);

  if (hops == ClockwiseHops(a, b))
    return String.Format("{0} -> {1} (clockwise) {2} hops", a, b, hops);
  else
    return String.Format("{1} -> {0} (anticlockwise) {2} hops", a, b, hops);
}
```

Tests:

```
 // 12 -> 1 (clockwise) 1 hops
 Console.WriteLine(Solve(12, 1));
 // 11 -> 4 (clockwise) 5 hops
 Console.WriteLine(Solve(11, 4));
```

Comment: Ah didn't see you had posted basically the same answer, posted at very similar times, I'll upvote yours as it's more concise.

Comment: @Vistari: and your answer is *explaining* what's going on, so +1 for teaching.

Comment: The problem here is the returned value doesn't indicate whether it is clockwise or anticlockwise. The OP doesn't ask for this, but I wonder if they should have.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: in that case (when/if direction is required) I suggest implementing `ClockwiseHops` as well as `AntiClockwiseHops` methods, then taking *min* as well as *argmin*, see my edit.

Comment: I was thinking you could calculate clockwise/anticlockwise hops like this (anticlockwise being negative, and clockwise preferred if there are 6 hops): `int clockwise = (end - start + 12) % 12; int anticlockwise = (start - end + 12) % 12; return Math.Abs(clockwise) <= Math.Abs(anticlockwise) ? clockwise : -anticlockwise;` (Assuming that `start <= end` !)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the `%` Modulo Operator? That will give you the remainder of of the first number divided by the second. For example:

`6 % 3 = 0` (3 goes into 6 exactly twice so zero remaining)

`10 % 4 = 2` (4 goes into 10 twice with a remainder of two)

So you will want to try both routes and then check which one is smaller.

so try:

```
int numberOfPositions = 12;
Math.Min ((numberOfPositions + b - a) % numberOfPositions, (numberOfPositions + a -b) % numberOfPositions);
```

If you would like to see how modulo calculations work then there's an online calculator here:
 http://www.miniwebtool.com/modulo-calculator/

Answer (score 0):

Is it this simple?

```
int NUM_OF_NODES = 12;
int numOfHops = NUM_OF_NODES;
int point1 = 11;
int point2 = 4;
int path1 = Math.Abs(point1 - point2);
int path2 = numOfHops - path1;
int result =  path1 < path2 ? path1 : path2;
return result;
```

For simple function

```
public int getLeastPath(int point1, int point2)
{
    int path1 = Math.Abs(point1 - point2);
    int path2 = NUM_OF_NODES - path1;
    return path1 < path2 ? path1 : path2;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answers were already provided but here's a recursive function, that actually "jumps" from one number to the other:

```
        Func<int, int, int, int> Hop = null; 
        Hop = (direction, start, end) =>
            {
                if (start < 1)
                    start = 12;

                if (start != end)
                    return 1 + Hop(direction, (start + direction), end);

                return 0;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

EX : 11-8

1.Get the mod of first number and last number
    11% 12 = 1

```
8 % 12 = 8
```

2. add the sum
   if it is less than 12 > 1 + 8 = 9 
   else sub
3. subtract with the 12 -9 = 3
4. compare  9 with 3, lesser value will be the answer.